# If a function is integrable from a to b, how can I show that it is also integrable on some smaller interval a to c?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

If I have a function $f$ that is integrable on [a,b], how can I show that it is also integrable on some interval [a,c], for some point c $\in$ (a,b)?

My attempt:

For all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a partition P such that $U(f,P)-L(f,P)<\epsilon$.  There exists a partition P' such that for all $\epsilon > 0$, $U(f,P')-L(f,P')<\epsilon$.  The point $c \in [a,b]$, so define P' to be all the points of P up to and including c, then it becomes apparent that this is true.

Is this correct and rigorous enough?  I feel that it's not much more than intuition but I'm not sure how to construct a more detailed proof.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: The Riemann-Lebesgue Theorem is a fairly straight-forward way to show this, but I don't know if that's available to you.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  That seems a bit outside of my current knowledge.  Is there a simpler way to prove the problem in the question? It makes sense to me intuitively but I'm stuck trying to prove it.

Comment: Your order is a bit off. When you write "There exists a partition $P'$..." you need to specify that it's only from $a$ to $c$ right then. You can't say there exists a $P'$ and then re-define it later. I would just delete the whole sentence beginning with "There exists a partition $P'$". Then you have to argue from subsets that the upper and lower sums will be even closer than with $P$.

Comment: Better to start with "let $\epsilon >0$" and simply deal with that one $\epsilon$ throughout.

Comment: this is related https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1872886/is-my-proof-of-the-additivity-property-of-riemann-integral-correct